# Python monkey patching objects not working as expected

Tags: python, object, python-2.7, instance, monkeypatching

I am trying to learn python monkey patching. I have a simple example where I am trying to monkey patch just a single instance rather than the class itself.

**My code:**

```
# add.py
import types


class Math(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''

    def add(self, x, y, name):
        self.name = name
        print 'calling from ', self.name
        return x + y

    def monkey_patch(self):
        add = self.add

        def squared_sum(x, y):
            return x**2 + y**2
        add = types.MethodType(squared_sum, self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    math = Math()
    print math.add(3, 4, 'before monkey_patching')
    math.monkey_patch()
    print math.add(3, 4, 'after monkey_patching')
```

**Expected Output:**

```
calling from  before monkey_patching
7
calling from  after monkey_patching
25
```

**Generated Output:**

```
calling from  before monkey_patching
7
calling from  after monkey_patching
7
```

Can someone point out where I am going wrong. And also how can I monkey patch the add method when I am doing it from a different file i.e. When I import Math class from add.py in a different file, how can I monkey patch it's add method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
def monkey_patch(self):
    add = self.add # add now points to self.add
    def squared_sum(x, y):
        return x**2 + y**2
    add = types.MethodType(squared_sum, self) # add now points to squared_sum
# method ends, add and squared_sum are abandoned
```

This doesn't actually *change* `self.add`. Also, `squared_sum` doesn't take `self` or `name` arguments, unlike `add`, and doesn't have the `print` that `add` does. To make this work fully, do:

```
def monkey_patch(self):
    def squared_sum(self, x, y, name):
        self.name = name
        print 'calling from ', self.name
        return x**2 + y**2
    self.add = types.MethodType(squared_sum, self)
```

To patch outside the class definition:

```
math = Math()

def func(self, x, y, name):
    return x ** y

math.add = types.MethodType(func, math)
```

Comment: Works perfect! Had a doubt. self.add = types.MethodType(squared_sum, self) shows instance attribute defined outside __init__ warning. Now how can I move the self.add into the constructor?

Comment: Are you using PyCharm or something? Of course you are "defining outside `__init__`", that's the *whole point* of what you're doing; you can ignore the warning.

Comment: exactly! I am using PyCharm!! Thanks a lot!